# How many document reads per minute is too many in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Function that runs a cron job every 1 minute. I've calculated that it has the potential to result in up to as many as ~120,500 document reads each time, so 173,520,000 document reads per day. Ignoring the obvious cost financially for a moment, is this something that Firestore can handle well? Will performance be terrible?

For a little more context, if it helps, the function first calls (hypothetically) a collection of 500 companies, each of which has about 20 fields. The function then loops over that collection and calls a sub collection of (hypothetically) 240 appointments for each company. Each appointment has about 15 fields. The function then loops over each of those and does a few simple operations. If my math is right, that's 120,000 document reads for appointments + the 500 reads for companies.

Is there a general rule of thumb for how many document reads per minute is too many as far as performance is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're proposing is a drop in the bucket for Firestore.  It scales massively for read operations.  The theoretical read limit is so high that that it's not even listed in the [documented limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  Note that all the significant limits are on write operations.  Those limits are what help Firestore scale massively.

There is only one piece of advice I'm aware of when it comes to read performance, and that runs only in [specific situations](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range), which is possible to avoid with care.

Comment: I was actually looking at that link before I posted this. No wonder I couldn't find read limits in there!